# What the warning "A web service endpoint could not be found"?

Tags: java, soap, jaxb

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://ekokontrol.lenobl.smev.ru", name="Ekokontrol")
@SOAPBinding(style=SOAPBinding.Style.RPC, use=SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL)
public interface EkokontrolIF {

    @WebMethod(operationName="inspection", action="urn:inspection")
    @WebResult(name="return")
    public BaseMessageType inspection(
        @WebParam(name="request")BaseMessageType requestBaseMessage);

}
```

> [annotationProcessing] Compiling 1 source file to
>   /home/sabo/workspace/ekokontrol/build/classes [annotationProcessing]
>   warning: A web service endpoint could not be found
>
> [annotationProcessing] 1 warning

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "ekokontrol.server.EkokontrolIF")
public class EkokontrolImpl {
...
}
```

What the warning "A web service endpoint could not be found"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "ekokontrol.server.EkokontrolIF")  
public class EkokontrolImpl implements EkokontrolIF {
...
}
```